# Using Distinct or Case to reduce results in query

Tags: sql, case, distinct

The scenario, which is a simple database about tennis, is:

- Select male players who have atleast two 'e' in their name. (This
  part fine)
- Show a list of them who **currently** have a `functie`(role) in
  the table board members (called `bestuursleden`). I've deduced this
  is when the column `eind_datum` (end date) is NULL for logical
  reasons as is in my query.
- Male players **currently without** a `functie` (function) should also
  be showed. This part where the problem is.

**Expected** Result:

```
naam (name)  | geslacht (gender)|   functie (role)
_____________|__________________|_______________
Permentier   | M                | Voorzitter
Bakker, de   | M                | NULL
Bohemen, van | M                | NULL
Meuleman     | M                | Penningmeester
Permentier   | M                | NULL
```

**My** Result (I am missing the name **Bohemen, van**):

```
naam (name)  | geslacht (gender)|   functie (role)
_____________|__________________|_______________
Permentier   | M                | Voorzitter
Bakker, de   | M                | NULL
Meuleman     | M                | Penningmeester
Permentier   | M                | NULL
```

My query:

```
SELECT naam AS role, geslacht AS gender, functie AS role
FROM spelers s LEFT JOIN bestuursleden b ON s.spelersnr = b.spelersnr
WHERE geslacht LIKE 'M' AND LOWER(naam) LIKE '%e%e%' AND eind_datum IS NULL
ORDER BY s.spelersnr
```

If I omit the **WHERE** check `AND eind_datum IS NULL` I get the following result, note I have added two columns for extra information (begin date and end date) to help determine wheter I could use a **CASE** or perhaps a specific **DISTINCT** function to help me keep the **Bohemen, van** record which is missing in my current query result:

```
naam (name)  | geslacht (gender)|   functie (role)| begin_date | end_date
_____________|__________________|_________________|____________|___________
Permentier   | M                | Secretaris      |  NOT NULL  | NOT NULL
Permentier   | M                | Lid             |  NOT NULL  | NOT NULL
Permentier   | M                | Penningmeester  |  NOT NULL  | NOT NULL
Permentier   | M                | Voorzitter      |  NOT NULL  | NULL
Bakker, de   | M                | NULL            |  NULL      | NULL
Bohemen, van | M                | Secretaris      |  NOT NULL  | NOT NULL    
Meuleman     | M                | Penningmeester  |  NOT NULL  | NULL
Permentier   | M                | NULL            |  NULL      | NULL
```

Its Postgres, using pgadmin as tool.

My Table definitions:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should upload your table definitions

Comment: @nacho ok, are questions like this one too long? Or is it okay to post such?

Comment: Can you also include a your query?

Comment: @MhQ-6 its in my post where it says My query:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as far as I understand, you want to display players and their current role, if they hold one. It's then better to include your `end_date` condition in the join statement, like so:

```
SELECT s.naam AS role
     , s.geslacht AS gender
     , b.functie AS role
  FROM spelers s 
  LEFT 
  JOIN bestuursleden b 
    ON s.spelersnr = b.spelersnr
   AND b.eind_datum IS NULL
 WHERE s.geslacht = 'M' 
   AND LOWER(s.naam) LIKE '%e%e%'
 ORDER BY s.spelersnr
```

This will only join the `bestuursleden` rows that have a `NULL` end date, meaning the most current one. If a player has an end date set, it won't be joined, so you will get `NULLs` in fields from the `bestuursleden`.

Note: **ALWAYS** use table aliases when referring to column names in queries that have a join. Otherwise people who are not familiar with your db will have no idea where is a given column coming from.

Comment: Omg this worked, placing the end_date condition in the join statement was what I needed and it makes sense. Thank you, this question was frustrating me so much, i appreciate ur time, and that note is noted